# How to select VM T-shirt size in Azure ARM Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have a VM deloyment template where i am defining the VM size as T-Shirt Sizes for example small = Standard_DS2_v2, medium = Standard_E4s_v3 and large = Standard_E4s_v3.

I have defined them as an array as shown below in variables section

```
 "parameters": {
        "vmSpecs": {
            "type": "array"
        }
},

"variables": {
        "vmSizeType" :[{
            "small" : "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "medium": "Standard_E4s_v3",
            "large" : "Standard_E32s_v3"
        }]
},

"resources": [
{
            "name": "[parameters('vmSpecs')[copyIndex()].vmName]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "VMNIC0Copy",
                "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            ],
            "copy": {
                "name": "VMCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('vmSpecs'))]"
            },

            "properties": {
                "licenseType": "[parameters('vmSpecs')[copyIndex()].licenseType]",
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSpecs')variables('vmSizeType')[copyIndex()].vmSize[1]]"
                }
}
```

In parameters file

```
"vmSpecs": {
            "value": [
                { //vm01
                    "vmName": "test",
                    "dnsDomain": "domain.com",
                    "vmSize": "medium"
                 }
           }
```

My question is how do i input vmSize and it selects the size based on what that has been defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you normally would (using dot notation) access object properties in almost any language:

```
"vmSizeType" :{ << should be an object, you only make it harder making it an array
    "small" : "Standard_DS2_v2",
    "medium": "Standard_E4s_v3",
    "large" : "Standard_E32s_v3"
}
...
"vmSize": "[variables('vmSizeType')[parameters('vmSpecs')[copyIndex()].vmSize]]"
            ^^ tshirt variable     ^ ^^ input parameter   ^^ iteration ^^ property
                                   ^ get property defined dynamically, have to use [] syntax instead of dot notation
                                     for static\hardcoded property name you can use dot notation:
                                     variables('vmSizeType').small
```

if you need tshirt variable to be array (no reason), you'd have to account for that as well